# Pass parameters to a service handler in rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `rospy`, message callbacks can have additional parameters, which allows me to write only one callback for different subscribers. For example:

```
def my_callback(msg, name):
    rp.logwarn(name + "has received the message: " + msg)

subscribers = [
    rp.Subscriber(
        name+'/my_topic',
        MyMessageType,
        my_callback,
        callback_args=name)
    for name in "Alice Bob Carl David".split()]
```

works perfectly fine. However, the same is not possible for service handlers. For example:

```
def my_hanlder(request, name):
    rp.logwarn(name + "has received the request: " + request)

providers = [
    rp.Service(
        name+'my_service',
        MyServiceType,
        my_handler,
        handler_args=name)
    for name in "Alice Bob Carl David".split()]
```

raises an error, because `handler_args` is not a parameter of the constructor `rp.Subscriber`.

How can I pass additional parameters to a service handler?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247540/pass-parameters-to-a-service-handler-in-rospy/) by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rospy.Service docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html) show that there isn't a parameter to the service constructor that allows it to pass arguments to the callback.

However, it's relatively easy to do this with a lambda:

```
def my_hanlder(request, name):
    rp.logwarn(name + "has received the request: " + request)

providers = [
    rp.Service(
        name+'my_service',
        MyServiceType,
        lambda msg: my_handler(msg, name))
    for name in "Alice Bob Carl David".split()]
```

(my apologies if there's a small syntax error in there; I don't use lambda very often)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2016-11-23**:
Yes, this was also my solution; but it has some faint "workaround" feel about it :)

**Comment by [mcmeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/121111/mcmeat/) on 2022-10-18**:
Not sure if this is an issue due to newer python, but the lambdas are dynamically called on msg income.
which means the last known 'name' is passed to all of them.

so for me all the my_hanlder calls report Dave is the receiver
to fix this :

```
providers = [
rp.Service(
    name+'my_service',
    MyServiceType,
    lambda msg, name_=name: my_handler(msg, name_))
for name in "Alice Bob Carl David".split()]
```